# Adding new rows on a draggable table via jquery

Tags: theming, 6, javascript

I have a draggable table with preloaded "new items" - sorta like the Power Edit feature of the menu_editor module. Everything works perfect.

However, I want to have a button that adds a new row via jquery. I was able to do this via the following code. However, the new rows added by jquery are not draggable. What can i do to make it work? Is it even possible?

```
var preloaded_items_count = '.$preloaded_items_count.';
$("#edit-add-new-item").click(function(){
  var append_tr = $("#guide-pages-table tr:last").clone();
  var replace_pattern = new RegExp("new-" + preloaded_items_count, "g");
  var new_item_id = "new-" + (preloaded_items_count + 1);

  //append_tr.find("a.tabledrag-handle").remove();
  append_tr.html(append_tr.html().replace(replace_pattern,new_item_id));
  preloaded_items_count = preloaded_items_count + 1;

  //Drupal.tableDrag.prototype.makeDraggable(append_tr);
  $("#guide-pages-table > tbody:last").append(append_tr);
  return false;
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As I can not reproduce your case, this answer just is a suggestion:

look at `misc/tabledrag.js`:

```
Drupal.tableDrag.prototype.makeDraggable = function (item) {
```

So you need re-running necessary javascript after adding new row.

```
Drupal.attachBehaviors($('#guide-pages-table > tbody:last'));
```

Comment: Yes, this is where I got the `Drupal.tableDrag.prototype.makeDraggable(append_tr);` idea. However, i still cannot make it work. I tried the `makeDraggable` function on my table, instead of the row, to no avail. Thanks btw.

Comment: Drupal.attachBehaviors($(this));

Comment: I am not entirely sure what `.attachBehaviors` will do. I tried adding `Drupal.attachBehaviors($('#guide-pages-table > tbody:last'));` at the bottom of my code but it still won't work :P

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it:
(For D7, I hope it is the same or similar in D6)

```
var $table = $('<table>').appendTo($container);
var $tbody = $('<tbody>').appendTo($table);
var drupalTableDrag = new Drupal.tableDrag($table[0], {});
var $newRow = $('<tr>').appendTo($tbody);
drupalTableDrag.makeDraggable($tr[0]);
```

The essential thing to learn is that Drupal.tableDrag acts as a class constructor, and you are supposed to call makeDraggable() from the constructed object.

If Drupal already created this object for you, you will find it in Drupal.tableDrag[base], where base is whatever key was used in the settings.